# Java str.replaceAll() doesn't recognize \R as part of a character class

Tags: java, regex

I can match `\\R` using str.replaceAll(), but when I try to match `[\\R]`, there is an exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence

Comment: What character class are you expecting `\R` to match?

Comment: Oh I've just learnt - from Java 8 onwards it's a linebreak matcher.  I never knew. 
 So, OP, which version of Java do you have?

Comment: `\R` Matches any Unicode line-break sequence

Comment: Huh, so it does.  I learned something today. `Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to \u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

Comment: Did you tried with `[\\\\R]`?

Comment: Dawood, I'm using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend replacing `\r?\n`:

```
str.replaceAll("\r?\n", "")
```

This covers both Windows (`\r\n`) and Unix (`\n`) line endings, which should cover your use case.

Comment: It doesn't work in Java 8. And note the beginning of the question.

Comment: @shmosel Yeah, I took that from an incorrect comment.

Comment: It doesn't work the same way in a character class though. Come to think of it, maybe that's the problem. `\R` represents a [sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527643/java-str-replaceall-doesnt-recognize-r-as-part-of-a-character-class/54527690#comment95857324_54527643), rather than a set, of characters, so it doesn't work in a character class.